# Is there a function to fill div´s with random img && random size?

Tags: javascript, sass

I got a grid of 40 squares and for that i have 7 dinosaur pictures.

i want to fill the divs with the pictures but randomly and the size should also be random from like 50-100%.

for what ? i want make a game for my young kid to learn mouse movement. when he mose over an image it will disappear and play sound - i got an idea how to make the sound and disappear but not for the filling part.  Asked Dr. Google but it seems there are ways in css and js or iam just stuck

kind regards

**CSS**

```
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.square {
  width: 10vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 25vh;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(18, 4, 250);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(18, 4, 250, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
<div class="row">
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that the layout is a grid and you can target each div by row and column.  You would need to have styles set for each image size.  You can use a random number to generate a location in the grid and a size for the image.  Something like:

```js
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function showImages() {
  let chosen = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    let row = getRandomNumber(0, 3);
    let col = getRandomNumber(0, 9);
    let imgSize = getRandomNumber(1, 6);
    let xy = row + "" + col;
    if (chosen.indexOf(xy) == -1) {
      let thisRow = document.querySelectorAll(".row")[row];
      let thisCell = thisRow.querySelectorAll(".square")[col];
      thisCell.classList.add("size" + imgSize);
      chosen.push(xy);
    } else {
      i--;
      continue;
    }
  }
}
// Use for testing purposes only
window.onload = showImages;
```

```css
body {padding:0px;}

.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.square {
  width: 10vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 24.8vh;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(18, 4, 250);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(18, 4, 250, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.size1 {background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Crystal_mozillacrystal.png"); background-size:30%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;}
.size2 {background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Crystal_mozillacrystal.png"); background-size:40%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;}
.size3 {background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Crystal_mozillacrystal.png"); background-size:50%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;}
.size4 {background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Crystal_mozillacrystal.png"); background-size:60%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;}
.size5 {background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Crystal_mozillacrystal.png"); background-size:70%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;}
.size6 {background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Crystal_mozillacrystal.png"); background-size:80%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="row">
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     <div class="square"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               <div class="square"></div>
               </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this website to get your images: https://picsum.photos/ ?
With this you can get a random image with a specified height and width. i.e. the URL https://picsum.photos/200/300 will resolve to a different images each time you use it

You could then either add a tag in your html for each square:

```
<div class="square"><img src ='https://picsum.photos/100'</img></div>
```

Or add them in via JS, and calculate a random image size each time:

```
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

squares.forEach((square) => {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  // Get random number between 100 and 150
  const size = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (150 - 100) + 100);
  img.setAttribute('src', `https://picsum.photos/${size}`);
  square.appendChild(img);
});
```

This solution would just require that that you use a different class for the squares which will hold the dinosaur pictures, i.e. `square--empty`

Comment: thank you very much !, but how can i add random local images.

Comment: tried implement that but isnt going off,function randomPic(){
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    return images[rand];
}; into your line. var images is an array with the img names   img.setAttribute('src', `img/${randomPic()}/${size}`);

Comment: So you've got the images you want to use already and you just want to be able to be able to display those images in a random order each time?